# What to assign a variable that I don't want to be equal to any possible input?

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is

> Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a
> sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the
> same value next to each other and preserving the original order of
> elements.
>
> For example:
>
> uniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB") == {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'}
>
> uniqueInOrder("ABBCcAD")         == {'A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D'}
>
> uniqueInOrder([1,2,2,3,3])       == {1,2,3}

Now my solution is

```
template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> uniqueInOrder(const std::vector<T>& iterable){
  std::vector<T> unique_set;
  T last = 0;
  for(auto & element : iterable) {
    if(element != last) {
      unique_set.push_back(element);
    }
    last = element;
  }
  return unique_set;
}
std::vector<char> uniqueInOrder(const std::string& iterable){
  std::vector<char> unique_set;
  char last = 0;
  for(auto & element : iterable) {
    if(element != last) {
      unique_set.push_back(element);
    }
    last = element;
  }
  return unique_set;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the first element is 0. What can I assign last that will never match an input? I tried using NULL but I think that just compiled to 0 anyway.

Comment: `std::optional` or if you must use C++11 a third-party version such as `boost::optional`. Or just keep a `bool` whether you found an element yet or not, and use that to track 'nullness'. And yes, `NULL` is just a macro for `0` cast to a pointer, and you shouldn't use it in C++ but `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Sounds like what [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) does.

Answer (score 5):

There's an algorithm to do just that called [`std::unique_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy)

```
template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> uniqueInOrder(const std::vector<T>& iterable){
  std::vector<T> unique_set;
  std::unique_copy(iterable.begin(), iterable.end(), std::back_inserter(unique_set));
  return unique_set;
}

// same thing for std::string
std::vector<char> uniqueInOrder(const std::string& iterable){
  std::vector<char> unique_set;
  std::unique_copy(iterable.begin(), iterable.end(), std::back_inserter(unique_set));
  return unique_set;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming back_inserter applies the push_back function?

Comment: @JoeyMoore Yes, you can read more about it at [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) and [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the type of `T`, there could be no impossible value. For ints and chars, every single value is possible. The best option is to use something like [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), which provides an explicit valueless value.

```cpp
// this will be valueless and not equal to any value
std::optional<T> last{};
// assign it with
last = element;
```

Answer (score 3):

As the first element in `iterable` will always be added you could also start with it anyways. So it get's added to the unique set and in the for loop it will be ommited anyways due to `if(element != last)` (or you could just start the loop with the second element).

```
template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> uniqueInOrder(const std::vector<T>& iterable){
  std::vector<T> unique_set;
  if(iterable.empty()) {
     return unique_set;
  }
  T last = iterable.at(0);
  unique_set.push_back(last);
  for(auto & element : iterable) {
    if(element != last) {
      unique_set.push_back(element);
    }
    last = element;
  }
  return unique_set;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this skips the first set of elements.

Comment: I can do this as well as add the first element but sometimes the input vector will be empty.

Comment: Damn, my brain left me there. Now it should be right. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

With Range-v3

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <vector>
using ranges::views::group_by;
using ranges::views::transform;
int main() {
    std::string s1 = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB";
    std::string s2 = "ABBCcAD";
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,2,3,3};
    auto process = group_by(std::equal_to<>{})
                 | transform([](auto x){ return x.front(); });
    std::cout << (s1 | process) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (s2 | process) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (v  | process) << std::endl;
}
```

I want to stress on the expressiveness of this solution. Indeed, at the "cost" of defining the following names,

```cpp
    constexpr auto equal = std::equal_to<>{};
    constexpr auto pick_first = [](auto x){ return x.front(); };
```

which in reality adds no complexity/cost at all, the important line becomes

```cpp
    auto process = group_by(equal) | transform(pick_first);
```

which reads almost like English: *The `process`ing consists in `group`ing `by` `equal`ity and piping (`|`) the result into a `transform`ation which `pick`s the `first` element of each group.*